# Do i need .ebextensions to use AWS resources like DynamoDB or SNS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, configuration-files, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was building a Python web-app with AWS Elastic Beanstalk, and I was wondering if it's necessary to need to create a **.ebextensions/xyz.config** file to use resources like DynamoDB, SNS, etc

here is a sample code using boto3 and I was able to connect from my web-app and put data into the table without defining any configuration files ...

```
db = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1')
table = db.Table('StudentInfo')
```

appreciate your inputs

Answer (score 0):

You do not *need* .ebextensions to create a DynamoDB to work with Beanstalk. However, you *can*, as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-environment-resources-dynamodb.html). This example uses the CloudFormation template syntax to specify a DynamoDB resource. If not in a .ebextensions file, you'd create the DynamoDB through an AWS SDK/Dynamo DB console and make the endpoint available to your Django application.

You can [specify an SNS topic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elasticbeanstalksnstopics) for Beanstalk to use to publish events to or as in the above DynamoDB example, create one as a CFN resource. The difference between the two approaches is that, whereas in the former, the Beanstalk environment owns the SNS topic, in the latter, it is the underlying CloudFormation stack that does. If you want to use the SNS topic for things other than to publish environment health events to, you would use the latter approach. For example, to integrate the SNS topic with DynamoDB, you must use the latter approach (i.e. , specify it as a resource in a ebextensions file, rather than as an option setting).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to switch to using IAM roles. Read more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-api.html).

I am assuming that you didn't change the default role that gets assigned to the Elastic Beanstalk (EB) instance during creation. The [default instance profile role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts-roles-instance.html) allows EB to utilize other AWS services it needs to create the various components.

Until you understand more about IAM, creating roles, and assigning permissions you can attach AWS managed permissions to this role to test your application (just search for Dynamo and SNS).